# OneNote Access from Several Computers?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I've connected to OneNote using my Microsoft account from two computers and my iPhone without issue. But I have tried unsuccessfully to access it from my laptop and not sure why.  You must have OneDrive for OneNote to sync across boxes correct? 
The logon to the OneNote with the Microsoft account should work from the laptop but keep getting an error saying can't access with that account.

Comment: OneNote by default stores your notebook in the cloud unless you don't store it in the cloud.  All versions of OneNote look to the cloud.  If you have a MS Account you have a OneDrive account, they are one in the same, more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You must have OneDrive for OneNote to sync across boxes correct?

- when you login using microsoft account and store the one notes on microsoft servers you are storing them on OneDrive, that's give

you might have an account issue or try using a different browser to launch the one drive and then open one note and then open in one note

these sync issues very common with one note